# не работает add_answer vk api python

Tags: python, json, vkontakte-api

```
import vk, const

session = vk.AuthSession(app_id = const.app_id1, user_login = const.login, 
user_password = const.passw, scope = 'wall' )

vkapi = vk.API(session)
```

Он просит чтобы Я ввел данные в последний параметр в формате json

```
vkapi.polls.create(owner_id="-162146428",question="Вопрос?",is_anonymous=0,
                   add_answers= )
```

Ниже информация из самого ВК `add_answers`

список вариантов ответов, например:

```
["yes", "no", "maybe"]
```

Может быть не менее 1 и не более 10 вариантов ответа. 
данные в формате `JSON`

Я не понимаю, что туда нужно внести.

Answer (score 0):

Так ведь в примере написано что - массив вариантов ответов. То есть у вас будет:
`["вариант ответа 1", "вариант ответа 2", "вариант ответа 3"]`
Это нужно записать в переменную и передать в параметре `add_answers`

Будет примерно так:

```
vkapi.polls.create(owner_id="-162146428", question="Вопрос?", is_anonymous=0,
                   add_answers="[\"yes\", \"no\", \"maybe\"]")
```

Comment: Большое спасибо @Nazar_Fazylov! Теперь скрипт работает и не выдает ошибок, но на стене ничего не появилось, Я имею в виду опрос. Скрипт исполнился, но не работает. Объясни мне пожалуйста как работает в данной ситуации комбинация ' "/ '

Comment: @Nazar_Fazylov, объект poll создался. Я понял, что теперь к посту на стене его надо приложить как вложение, ошибок не выдает но и опроса не появляется
    vkapi.wall.post(owner_id='-162146428',message = 'zhopa',attachments = poll)

Comment: А что находится в переменной poll? Должно работать, если строка вида poll123_123